# Is there a way to reduce "gross total income" in ITR? (India)

Tags: income-tax, india, income, adjusted-gross-income

I'm an Indian student trying to decide my college. There's a really good college I'd like to join (can't mention its name for privacy reasons) but its annual fees is absymally high (close to triple of the average fees of Indian colleges). The said college offers fee waiver to certain students whose family's annual "gross income" is less than a certain amount, say Rs.5,00,000. My father's Income Tax Return says that his gross income is Rs.5,11,000. Is there a way to decrease this value? We don't have a problem with losing those Rs.11,000. So, if we can, say donate the 11,000 to some NGO, it'd be fine too.

Please note that unlike the usual question, this question isn't about tax saving. It's fine if we still have to pay tax on those Rs.11,000. It's just that the figure in "Gross Total Income" needs to say Rs.5,00,000.

Comment: You seem to be trying to cheat the system...

Comment: @Flux Nope. I'm asking if there's a legitimate way to "give up" income. Like if a shopowner wanted to do this, they'd, lets say, open their shop for one day less per month. I don't see how that shopowner is cheating anyone. But, this simple thing won't work as my dad is salaried, not businessman

Comment: If he is a government employee, nothing can be done.  If he was working in small company, he could ask for reduction in salary,  but it will still not fix the older ITRs.

Answer (score 3):

They have defined a rule to benefit low income people. Your father's salary comes closer to that. In that case, you can talk with University and tell them that your father salary is very slightly higher than the suggested salary and try to get waive off.

Also, you can tell them that even though gross salary is this much, after tax the net salary is this much.

If they don't agree of any of these things, I would suggest you to pay the fee they suggest, if you are thinking about joining there. Rule is a Rule.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way would be your dad going to his employer and ask to work for less money. Unless the employer cannot pay less for some legal reason, or there is a totally inflexible bureaucracy, that should be no problem.

Also check what *exactly* their rules are. Is it really “gross income”, not for example “taxable income”?

Comment: He's a govt employee. Is it possible for a govt employee to request reduction in his income?

Comment: “Unless there is a totally inflexible bureaucracy”. He can ask, but that will be difficult.

Comment: It uses the word "gross income"